# Add Parameter to DocuSign PageReference

Tags: docusignapi

For the record, I have already reached out to support directly, and they asked me to post my question here.

In the DocuSign Console we have created a binding to the Signer Attachment Tab. We would like to bind `conditionalParentLabel` and `conditionalParentValue` values to it, but they are not available from the UI. So we send this template off to Conga and they send us back an envelope. Then a user has to go in and manually tag these values so the attachment is conditionally required.

Is there a way to use the API to edit the existing envelope to add these properties to the Signer Attachment Tab?

Answer (score 1):

Do I understand correctly that if you examine an Attachment tag's properties (within an Envelope) in the DocuSign Console, you're not seeing the **Conditional Fields** section that I've highlighted in the following screenshot?

[image: Attachment Properties]

If that's true (i.e., you're not seeing the "Conditional Fields" section when looking at the Tab's properties), then you might just need to enable the **Allow Conditional SecureFields** setting for the DocuSign Account.  In the DocuSign Console, navigate to **Preferences >> Features** and make sure this checkbox is selected (then click the SAVE button at the very bottom of the page to save the setting):

[image: DS Setting]

Enabling that setting should allow you to see/set **Conditional Fields** properties for a Tab (within an Envelope) in the DocuSign Console.

If that doesn't work for you, then back to your original question -- it IS possible to modify a tag's properties by using the API -- but ONLY for DRAFT Envelopes. See "Modify Tabs for a Recipient" in the DocuSign REST API guide for request/response info (pages 144-145):  https://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf.

Comment: No. I see those fields. What I am trying to do is auto-populate them with specific values.

Comment: In that case, the last paragraph of my answer applies:  it's possible to set those properties for an existing envelope using the API, but only for DRAFT envelopes. If the envelope's already been sent, those properties cannot be set/modified.